# Zeppelin - Spark 1.6 issues with dependencies

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

Recently, dependencies have migrated from worksheet to interpreter as per below screenshot:
[image]

Unfortunately, when applying dependencies as per below:
[image]

The error is produced when calling spark context: 
[image]

or another one as `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.deser.BigDecimalDeserializer$.handledType()Ljava/lang/Class`

does anyone know how to fix it?
I removed jackson libraries without any result:

```
rm -f zeppelin-server/target/lib/jackson-*
rm -f zeppelin-zengine/target/lib/jackson-*
```

and tried to upload com.fasterxml.jackson.core into artifact in dependencies but this does not exist in https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to input dependencies into /usr/local/zeppelin/conf/zeppelin-env.sh

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr
```

## export MASTER=local[*]

export ZEPPELIN_PORT=8081

export SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS="--packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.2.0"

which works fine